# interpreting object for form append to DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, forms, api

I was writing a function to convert a json object to a form,  appending it to the DOM.

I can't seem to get my syntax right; chrome dev tools gives me a "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier" error at line 15.

I am trying to support form cases such as radio, checkbox and the standard text or textbox. I am not sure how to differentiate radio from a checkbox.

Here is what I have so far:

```
jQuery.fn.toForm = function(obj) {

var target = this; 

var form = document.createElement("form");
    form.setAttribute('method', "post");
    form.setAttribute('action', "submit.php");

$.each(obj, function(key, value){

    var inputCheckbox = $("<input type='checkbox' value='"+value+"' />");
    var inputStandard = $("<input type='text' value='"+value+"' />");

    if(typeOf value === 'boolean'){

        inputCheckbox.attr("id", key).attr("name", key).appendTo("form");
        form.append(inputCheckbox);
    }
    else {
        inputStandard.attr("id", key).attr("name", key).appendTo("form");
    }   

    target.append(form); 
});
};
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: typeOf should be typeof (lower case o), I think you have an error in your JSON string but you didn't post that.

Comment: form.append doesn't exist, should that not be form.appendChild?

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to be in the line

```
inputCheckbox.attr("id", key).attr("name", key).appendTo("form");
```

JQuery can be unreliable at appending to elements that are not yet in the dom (I believe this particularly applies to JQuery 1.9+ - see http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/8858 (last comment) for confirmation of the bug).

If you move the

```
target.append(form);
```

to above the if statement you may find this solves your problem